# Is the following IP-Range 100.64.0.0/10 reserved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ip, ip-address

I am going to check if an IP-Adresse is private or reserved (e.g. multicast adress space).

My Methode is looking like this at the moment:

```
def __IP4_POR(ip):

if(ipaddress.ip_address(ip).is_private or 
   ipaddress.ip_address(ip).is_reserved or 
   ipaddress.ip_address(ip).is_multicast): return str(1)
else: return str(0);
```

So the problem is that the python compiler will return me 0, if the IP is in range 100.64.0.0/10.

The question is: Why does the compiler returns a 0? Because when I look at the IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry I see that the IP-Adress must be according to RFC6598 IETF reserved and the compiler should return 1 and not 0.

Is that maybe a bug in the python lib?

I hope you can help me with a little explanation.

Thank you!

edit: I am using Python 3.6.5

Comment: Why are you returning strings instead of Boolean `True` or `False`?

Comment: Because other methods are handling with strings :'D But that is not the main problem so far^^

Comment: You should get that fixed and afterwards remove the semicolon, it's not beautiful.

Comment: Yeah but code optimization is the last point on my list. At the moment I need the funcionality of the method "is reserved". But thank you for your points! :)

Answer (score 0):

From ipaddress module, 100.64.0.0/10 is not reserved. Only 240.0.0.0/4 is reserved ip address.